# running a multinominal nested regression

Tags: regression

I have a dataset that includes
(1) whether a student passes or fails an examination and without going into detail is being considered as a continuous numerical variable on a scale of 0 to 1
(2) valency scores from comments on student's performances, also continuous on a scale of -5 to +5 (including a neutral 0)
(3) profile membership which is the result of a latent class analysis that groups the same students who failed or passed the exam from (1) into 4 profiles based on other scores.

What I want to do do is see if the students (1) score on an exam and (2) their valency score can predict which profile they will fall into.  I am trying to write a multinominal regression but having a lot of trouble because of nesting. I have about 1000 students and Multiple students fall into the pass and fail category as well as into each profile.

A sample of my data looks like this

[image]

where blineid is a unique identifier to each student, profile is the profile the student is placed into (profile 2 is the lowest performing, 1, 4, then 3 the best) fail is student grade (0 is pass, 1 is fail) and value is the valency score.

I have been trying variations of this code with no success.
model<- mlogit(profile ~ value + fail + blineid, afinnR,
nests = list(profile = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), fail = c("0", "1")))